# Laravel artisan is not reading argument date linux string

Tags: linux, laravel, cron

I have written a custom command that has 1 argument which is the current time (in string format)

```
artisan check-banners $(date +%X)
```

The argument is then passed to the fire method and I can successfully insert the current time into the database. However... when i try to cronjob this custom command it does not work. see code below:

```
* * * * * php /Applications/AMPPS/www/laravel/artisan check-banners $(date +%X)
```

I have tried insert `'foo'`instead of `$(date +%X)` as an argument and it successfully inserts into the database.

Why can't I insert this `$(date +%X)` through the cronjob?? But I can manually type it via `artisan check-banner $(date +%X)` and it works

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Percentage signs have special meaning in crontab and need to be escaped, like so:

```
* * * * * php /Applications/AMPPS/www/laravel/artisan check-banners $(date +\%X)
```

Also, I'm not sure, but you may need to wrap the +%X argument in quotes as well:

```
* * * * * php /Applications/AMPPS/www/laravel/artisan check-banners $(date "+\%X")
```